# How do I update a Minecraft skin from a script if I have the account ID and password?

Tags: node.js, minecraft

In my script (below) I can fetch a minecraft skin for *USERNAME* at http://skins.minecraft.net/MinecraftSkins/*USERNAME*.png

How do I do the "opposite":  update a Minecraft skin if I have the account username and password?

```
var http = require('http')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , options

options = {
    host: 'skins.minecraft.net'
  , port: 80
  , path: '/MinecraftSkins/Notch.png'
}

var request = http.get(options, function(res){
    var imagedata = ''
    res.setEncoding('binary')

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        imagedata += chunk
    })

    res.on('end', function(){
        fs.writeFile('logo.png', imagedata, 'binary', function(err){
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('File saved.')
        })
    })

})
```

Comment: which node.js module do you use or which tool/library to do this?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, per the above snippet I'm using the 'http' and 'fs' modules.  However I'd be happy to use any module for http requests, it looks like quite a few are available!

Comment: By the way I'm aware of the [Yggdrasil Minecraft authentication protocol](http://wiki.vg/Authentication) but thats for Minecraft game servers, not the server(s) that manage Minecraft profiles.